# What is condition of set C where Point-wise supremum

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In  convex optimization,

$$
g=\underset{y\in C}{\mathop{\sup }}\,f(x,y)
$$

where $f$ is convex in $x$ for each $y$, $y$ is belong to $C$.

we know that $g(x)$ is convex in $x$

I have two questions which are associated each other

1. what should $C$(set of $y$) satisfy condition for $g$ is convex of $x$
2. In case of $g=\underset{y\in \{y\left| y\le h(x)\} \right.}{\mathop{\sup }}\,\,\,f(x,y)$ , this $g$ is also convex????

Comment: Did you reread your question after you posted it? Please be sure your markup is correct, use LaTeX formatting (easy to Google), and proofread. I am barely able to read through this!

Comment: sorry about that, I edited that, thank you for pointing out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $C$ may not depend on $x$. Otherwise, even for a discrete set $C$, the function $h$ is convex since the supremum of convex functions is convex and that for fixed $y$, the function $h_y(x) = f(x,y)$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks for answer! ,So, even If $y=\{y\left| y=h(x) \right.\}$ , $g(x)$ is convex?
for example $f(x,y)=x*y$ at that time, I think
$g=\underset{y\in \{y\left| =h(x)\} \right.}{\mathop{\sup }}\,f(x,y)=xh(x)$
so I think that it depends on form of $h(x)$.

Comment: My very bad. The set $C$ may not depend on $x$.

Comment: Could I ask any reference about "The set $C$ may not depend on $x$??

Comment: If the set $C$ does not depend on $x$, the collection of functions that you take the maximum over is fixed. The maximum of a (fixed) set of convex functions is convex, see [this book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), section 3.2.3.